# Aceder a class PHP com AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho o ficheiro file.js na pasta:

```
folder1\folder-xpto\js\c3-0.4.11\file.js
```

Este ficheiro tem o seguinte script `AJAX`:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'controller/classX.php',
    dataType : 'html',
    data : {
        var1 : 12,
        varId : 87
    },
    beforeSend : function() {
    },
    complete : function() {
    },
    success : function(options) {
        alert(options);
    },
    error : function(xhr, er) {
    }
});
```

E pretendo aceder ao ficheiro `classX.php` que está aqui:

```
folder1\folder2\classX.php
```

No ficheiro `classX.php` tenho o seguinte script para validar e pegar o valor enviado:

```
    if (isset ( $_POST ['varId'] )) {
        echo 'recebido';
// ...
    }
```

Já tentei vários formas, colocando `'./'` ou `'../'`, etc, no URL, mas não consigo.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isto?

Comment: O interessante seria colocar a `url` completa

Comment: Você deve colocar na URL o caminho correto que ele se encontra

Comment: '../../../folder2/classX.php', são necesários 3 retornos, 1° para 'js', 2° para 'folder-xpto', e 3° para 'folder1', entre em folder 2 pegue o arquivo, ou coloque a url toda http://urlatéfolder1/folder2/classX.php

Comment: Coloque o código completo do arquivo PHP na pergunta, por favor. Da maneira que explicou, dá a entender que está tentando executar um método da classe sem ao menos instanciá-la. Com a parte do código PHP que apresentou, não há como dizer se realmente fez isso ou não.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : '../folder2/controller/classX.php',
    dataType : 'html',
    data : {
        var1 : 12,
        varId : 87
    },
    beforeSend : function() {
    },
    complete : function() {
    },
    success : function(options) {
        alert(options);
    },
    error : function(xhr, er) {
    }
});
```